# Use a non-defined variable in a function in a function where said non-defined variable is being defined

Tags: python

I want to run a function (myfunc2) and call another function (myfunc) within this function. myfunc returns the sum of x and y but doesnt define y. y is just being defined in myfunc2. Is it possible to run this without running into a NameError without using `return myfunc(x,y)` or using `global y`?

```
def myfunc(x):
    return x+y

def myfunc2(x):
    y = 4
    return myfunc(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(myfunc2(10))
```

Comment: Any reason not to pass y?

Comment: If you really need to use global variables, check out this [w3schools article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp).

Comment: You seem to think that Python uses dynamic scope, but it doesn't, it use static scope (like pretty much all languages made in the last 20 years). So the `y` in your function will ve looked up *globally*, not based on *where it is called*

Comment: As noted, the most reasonable thing to do here is to take `y` ad an argument

Comment: @2e0byo My bad not to clarify. Actually I am new to a project as a junior and I was in front of this function that had this really deep function chain(?) like imagine its not myfunc2 but myfunc30 calling myfunc29 calling myfunc28 etc., but only myfunc1 needs like 2 new arguments (its building a query string).I actually implemented it first passing the arguments through all those functions but was wondering if I could "unclutter" the arguments in myfunc2 to myfunc29 who dont directly need those arguments.

Comment: @BaranCalisci this sounds like a different problem.  Encapsulating the state representing a particular query is definitely worth solving, but on the other hand that state *does* belong in the functions.  You can either make the functions methods on a class and store the state there (so you do `self.param1` etc), and pass the state in when you initialise the object, or wrap up all the required state in an object (probably a namedtuple or dict) and pass that to every function (`def do_query(query: QueryParams)`).  However for a mere two arguments it may be simpler to keep what you have.

Comment: @BaranCalisci and it's really worth giving the context if you're not sure about it!  Seems this was a classic case of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  We could have given much more useful answers about how to structure that kind of code if you'd asked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass state around, there are two options: pass it explicitly, or put in a variable within the scope of the second object.

In this case if there is some reason *not* to pass the state, but it isn't global, you may be looking for a closure:

```py
def f1(x):
    y = 7
    def f2(x):
        nonlocal y
        return x * y
    return f2(x)
```

If you are actually just doing this avoid passing y every time, use `functools.partial` to construct the closure for you.  We call this a closure as the scope of `f1` 'closes over' `y`.  `y` is not global, but it is available inside `f2`.

If `y` should be global, use global scope.  Global variables are not *bad*, they should just be used *when you actually have global state* (and when storing that state in a variable makes sense).  Outside of small scripts there are usually only a few instances of truly global state.  Even that state can be hard to reason about.

However in the example you give, `y` should be passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make use of either local or global variable y, then there is no way of accomplishing your request. For the most cases, best practice is to define all the variables used in the function in input arguments (e.g. `def myfunc(x, y): return x+y`).